# Shopify custom field for create account

Tags: shopify

I am a novice when it comes to coding.
I was just wondering if you could please help me write some code, basically when a customer creates an account on the website I want them to add their date of birth.  Now I need that date of birth to be able to be automatically added on the invoices that I have setup to be auto generated.

Like how do I create one of these things for date of birth: 
{{ shipping_address.city }} (this Is the code on the invoice and will find the customers address and insert into the invoice) how can I do this for D.O.B? Do I have to create a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

The [Shopify help](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/communication/get-more-information-with-customer-registration-form) tells how to do this. In fact birthday is one of their examples.

As far as getting that on the invoice you would follow the [information about cart attributes](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/cart/get-more-information-with-cart-attributes).

However the trick is hooking these up so that the customer only has to enter their info once. This is easy enough with a scripted app but if you want to just collect this on the order and then use it for future orders then use a cart attribute only.

Then force the customer to register/login before you let them go to the checkout and use the following to pull the date of birth from the most recent order that has one:

```
<label>What is your Date of Birth?</label>
      {% assign dob = '' %}
      {% for pastOrder in customer.orders %}
          {% for attr in  pastOrder.attributes %}
      <p>{{ attr | first }}: {{ attr | last }}</p>
            {% assign attrName = attr | first %}
            {% if attrName == 'Date of Birth' %}{% assign dob = attr |last %}{% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
        <input type="text" name="attributes[Date of Birth]" value="{{ dob }}">
```